# Why sikuli desktop operation not working while running jar with ec2 startup script?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, executable-jar, sikuli, user-data

I have created windows AMI and in user data I am running command to run jar file, but jar running as a service when instance starts and jar unable to perform desktop click with sikuli. Same jar run perfectly fine if I manually start cmd on instance and run command for jar file.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have active UI to perform UI actions. Service is headless.

This is not a Sikuli specific problem